# How do i convert the Maclaurin Series for tan x equation to python code?

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to calculate the nth term but its giving me wrong answers

```py
import math

def bernoulli(m):
    if m == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        t = 0
        for k in range(0, m):
            t += math.comb(m, k) * bernoulli(k) / (m - k + 1)
        return 1 - t

def pn(n, x):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(n):
        sum += ((bernoulli(2 * i)) / math.factorial(2 * i)) * (-4**i) * (1 - (4**i)) * (x**((2 * i) - 1))
```

Equation:

[image]

Comment: "giving me wrong answers": For example?

Comment: In python, the convention is to include the start, and exclude the end. `list(range(1,4))` is only `[1, 2, 3]`, not `[1,2,3,4]`. Thus your loop should be `for k in range(0, m+1)`

Comment: Also, `-4**i` is parsed as `-(4**i)`, not as `(-4)**i`

Comment: Also, `sum` is the name of a builtin function in python. It is very strongly advised not to shadow the names of builtins. Call that variable `s` or `total` or something else, not `sum`.

Comment: @ScottHunter pn(2, 0.5) should be 0.54166666666666, it give 0.50000000002

Comment: @Stef OMG it worked. Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Do i just mark this as answered?

Comment: Your loop in `pn` is wrong too. Your formula has a sum from 1 included to n included, but your for-loop goes from 0 included to n excluded. It should be `for i in range(1, n+1)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few comments:

- In python, the convention is to include the start, and exclude the end. `list(range(1,4))` is only `[1, 2, 3]`, not `[1,2,3,4]`. Thus your Bernouilli loop should be `for k in range(0, m+1)` and your `pn` loop should be `for i in range(1, n+1)`.
- Exponentiation has a higher precedence than most operators. `-4**i` is parsed as `-(4**i)`, not as `(-4)**i`.
- `sum` is already the name of a builtin function in python. It is very strongly advised not to shadow the names of builtins. Call that variable `s` or `total` or something else, not `sum`.

Finally, the code becomes:

```py
import math

def bernoulli(m):
    if m == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        t = 0
        for k in range(0, m+1):
            t += math.comb(m, k) * bernoulli(k) / (m - k + 1)
        return 1 - t

def pn(n, x):
    s = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        s += ((bernoulli(2 * i)) / math.factorial(2 * i)) * ((-4)**i) * (1 - (4**i)) * (x**(2 * i - 1))
    return s
```

And, using builtin function `sum`:

```py
import math

def bernoulli(m):
    if m == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 - sum(math.comb(m, k) * bernoulli(k) / (m - k + 1)
                       for k in range(0, m+1))

def pn(n, x):
    return sum((bernoulli(2 * i)) / math.factorial(2 * i)) * ((-4)**i) * (1 - (4**i)) * (x**(2 * i - 1)
               for i in range(1, n+1))
```

Comment: I was gunna quote your comment and answer it here. Thankyou again Sir :)